# Postgis reporting a point is 1216m away from itself using ST_Distance

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis, geometry

I have a table containing a geometry column in 4236 projection. I take the ST_X and ST_Y values from one row, and create a point from them. I then transform the point and the original geometry column value into 3857 projection to get a 2d distance between then using ST_DISTANCE. I expect the distance to be ~0. The answer I actually get it 1216.something metres.

Here is example code which creates two points, which should be identical, and takes the distance between them, giving the same ~1216m answer

```
select ST_Distance(
               ST_Transform(
                       ST_SetSRID(
                               ST_MakePoint(5.6100, 58.8900), 4236),
                       3857),
               ST_Transform(
                       ST_SetSRID(
                               ST_MakePoint(5.6100, 58.8900), 4326),
                       3857));
```

I'm presumably making some stupid mistake here (I am by no means a GIS expect), but what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The two points use different ellipsoids.

EPSG:4**32**6 is WGS 84.
EPSG:4**23**6 is Hu Tzu Shan 1950.

Comment: Doh! Killed by a typo - thanks for spotting that, that explains the difference between the two "identical" points that I couldn't understand

Answer (score 0):

The converting brings always a certain inaccuracy.

> ```
> select ST_Distance(
>                ST_Transform(
>                        ST_SetSRID(
>                                ST_MakePoint(5.6100, 58.8900), 4236),
>                        3857),
>                ST_Transform(
>                        ST_SetSRID(
>                                ST_MakePoint(5.6100, 58.8900), 4326),
>                        3857));
> ```
>
> ```
> | st_distance       |
> | :---------------- |
> | 1216.975464330136 |
> ```

> ```
> select ST_Distance(
>                
>
>                'SRID=4326;POINT(5.6100 58.8900)'::geometry,
>                                       'SRID=4326;POINT(5.6100 58.8900)'::geometry
>                                );
> ```
>
> ```
> | st_distance |
> | :---------- |
> | 0           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc6de7df5eaa9d5d25bae3bcb94b8a19)*

Comment: Even though it's converting the same point both times?

Comment: you need to get the wanted input for ST_Distance

Comment: I don't understand this point at all - I found the link on using cos() to adjust for distortion, which is fine when comparing 2 different points, but how can there be a difference between 2 identical points, as in the example?

Comment: ST_SetSRID brings the difference factorfactor

Answer (score 0):

It's distorted by the conversion.  In the docs https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html it points this out.

"Corrected by cos(lat) to account for distortion"

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(5.6458 58.8816)'::geometry, 3857), 
    ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(5.6458 58.8816)'::geometry, 3857)) * 
    cosd(58.8816);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the whole issue was caused by a typo - the cut-down example posted included the typo for the SRID which was present, and causing the issue, in the original source.

Doh!

Comment: You should accept CL's answer, click the checkbox below the vote button